# Cheap coax for wifi antenna (RG-6, etc. instead of LMR-400?)

Tags: wireless-networking

I've converted a satellite dish into a WiFi antenna and it seems to be
working pretty well, but it presently has a foot long cable running from
the little double diamond antenna head to the router. This isn't
terribly practical for permanent installation! Here's my question:
normal LMR-400 coax for a WiFi antenna seems really expensive. Is it possible to use some other type of coax, such as RG-6 that is cheaper and more readily available as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

RG-6/U has an impedance of 75Ω, whereas LMR-400 and similar have a characteristic impedance of 50Ω. [This source](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/11305-43-cable-impedance#r8177289) quotes a loss of only 0.18dB; though [a reply](http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/11305-43-cable-impedance#r8177319) shows that that could actually be anywhere between 0dB and 0.7dB.

> Theoretically, you could tune your 75Ω-feedline's length to be precisely a multiple of the wavelength — i.e. a multiple of 5.75cm for the 5GHz channels 36–48, or a multiple of 5.20cm for the 5.8GHz channels 149–161, so on and so forth — but that's a failing game, as that'd break down if your router auto-selects channels, or if your router transmits on both the 2.4GHz and various 5GHz frequencies using the same antenna port.

None of this addresses how the VSWR of ≤2.25:1 will affect the possibly-delicate circuitry of your router's WiFi transceiver, though. I can't speak as to the engineering constraints of that hardware, but it seems reasonable to assume that since such devices are *not* built to be used with aftermarket antennas, that they are also not built to tune the transmission power to the severity of the reflection coefficient — so instead of having a weak signal thanks to the above, you might actually *destroy your router*.

**tl;dr**: Don't do that. Spend the money on the appropriate coaxial cabling, or gank a length of it off of a friend *(-ly HAM!)*